# Backup script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I need to write a script that will look for all files with the suffix ~ (eg file.txt ~) in current directory. If the script  will find something, it should be copied to BACKUP directory.

If the BACKUP directory does not exist, the script should create it. If there is already a file (or other non-directory) named BACKUP, the script should report an error.

The problem is that on line `if [ $x -eq BACKUP.* ];`. Bash shows `if [ $x -eq BACKUP.* ];`

Appreciate any help

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d BACKUP ]; 
then
    mkdir BACKUP;
fi
for x in *. *~ ; do
    if [ $x -eq BACKUP.* ]; 
    then
        echo "Error, file BACKUP exist";
    else
        cp ./$x ./BACKUP;
    fi
done
```

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc. Shellcheck produces three findings for your code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP=./BACKUP

if [[ -e "$BACKUP" ]]; then
    echo "$BACKUP already exists!" >&2 
    exit 1
fi

mkdir "$BACKUP"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*~" -exec cp {} "$BACKUP" \;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you ! Sorry that I can't give you my vote yet ;/

Comment: If the answer is helping you to find the solution, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and mark with a green hook, thx.